# Why can't open4 read from stdout when the program is waiting for stdin?

Tags: ruby, stdout, iostream, io, open4

I am using the `open4` gem and having problems reading from the spawned processes stdout. I have a ruby program, `test1.rb`:

```
print 'hi.' # 3 characters
$stdin.read(1) # block
```

And another ruby program in the same directory, `test2.rb`:

```
require 'open4'

pid, stdin, stdout, stderr = Open4.popen4 'ruby test1.rb'
p stdout.read(2) # 2 characters
```

When I run the second program:

```
$ ruby test2.rb
```

It just sits there forever without printing anything. Why does this happen, and what can I do to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to change `test1.rb` to this. I don't know why.

```
print 'hi.' # 3 characters
$stdout.flush
$stdin.read(1) # block
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, everything that you `print`to stdout or to another file is written into a buffer of Ruby (or the standard C library, which is underneath Ruby). The content of the buffer is forwarded to the OS if one of the following events occurs:

- The buffer gets full.
- You close stdout.
- You have printed a newline sequence (`\n')
- You call `flush` explicitly.

For other files, a `flush` is done on other occasions, too, like `ftell`.

If you put stdout in unbuffered mode (`$stdout.sync = true`), the buffer will not be used.

stderr is unbuffered by default.
The reason for doing buffering is efficiency: Aggregating output data in a buffer can save many system call (calls to operating system). System calls are very [expensive](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/kevgrig/entry/approximate_overhead_of_system_calls9?lang=en): They take many hundreds or even thousands of CPU cycles. Avoiding them with a little bit of code and some buffers in user space results in a good speedup.

A good reading on buffering: [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in process.

From my first sight of API document, the sequence of using open4 is like this:
first send text to stdin, then close stdin and lastly read text from stdout.

So. You can the `test2.rb` like this

```
require 'open4'

pid, stdin, stdout, stderr = Open4.popen4 'ruby test1.rb'
stdin.puts "something" # This line is important
stdin.close # It might be optional, open4 might close itself.
p stdout.read(2) # 2 characters
```